# Android Quick Settings notifications?

Tags: android, location

In gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi, the way to check if location settings are enabled is to call checkLocationSettings. That's great for polling, but it's possible for the user to turn location on/off using the new Quick Settings menu (swipe down from top), which does not necessarily trigger onResume in the top activity (if location is turned on, there's a dialog, but if it's turned off, there isn't one).

What's the right way to get notified when a Quick Setting toggles Location?

Comment: Did you have a service for location updates?

Comment: What do you mean by "a service for location updates"?

Comment: I mean you have an android service to get location updates For example  using LocationManager class.

Comment: Yes, I use FusedLocationProviderApi. The reason why your question is confusing is a Service is a specific term in Android, but it seems that's not what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is... android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED is broadcast when a change is made to location in Quick Settings.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".LocationProvidersChangedReceiver"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```